# Will a subclass use a super or sub class method when calling an inherited method (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance

If I have two methods in a superclass, call them a() and b(), and b() calls a(), and I have a subclass which overrides a(), then, if I call b() on an instance of the subclass, will it use the variant of a() in the superclass or the one in the subclass?

Thanks in advance for any answers: I haven't found anything in searching because the question is kind of hard to phrase as a search term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will call the one in the subclass. You could design an experiment to test for yourself:

```
class Super {
    void a() { System.out.println("super implementation"); }
    void b() { System.out.println("calling a()..."); a(); }
}


class Sub extends Super {
    void a() { System.out.println("sub implementation"); }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub x = new Sub();
        x.b();
        // Prints:
        //   calling a()...
        //   sub implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: this is due to `a()` implicitly becoming `this.a()`, and `this` is always the calling object. The calling object is of class `Sub`, so it will always start looking there for the method to invoke.

Comment: Side notes for extra confusion: In C++ (not Java!), omitting the `virtual` keyword means that the superclass will still call its own `a()` method. And within a C++ constructor, all methods are treated as non-virtual, unlike Java.